# "Никуда не годен"

Tags: стилистика

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли сказать "никуда не годен" или правильно будет только "ни на что не годен"?

Answer (score 1):

Выражения часто взаимозаменяемы, но определенные различия в семантике есть.

Ни на что не годен - нельзя использовать для каких-либо целей.

Никуда не годен - значение более обобщенное, переносное: не только бесполезный, но и вообще плохой.

Если речь идет о человеке, то используют обе формы, а вот про одежду лучше сказать "сюртук никуда не годен", так как предназначение у этого предмета только одно.

Примеры

1) Мне хочется говорить о вас, дать вам несколько советов: больше я ни на что не годен… И. C. Тургенев.

Буду краток, ― заговорил он отрывисто и веско. ― Полк никуда не годен. Солдат не браню, обвиняю начальников. А. И. Куприн.

Оказалось, что я никуда не годен: не умею ходить по вспаханной земле, не умею держать вожжи и править лошадью, не умею заставить ее слушаться С. Т. Аксаков.

2) Я тотчас же отправился покупать платье, потому что мой сюртук за дорогу стал никуда не годен. Г.И. Успенский.

Говорят, в Воронежской и Тамбовской губернии урожай оказался никуда не годен!

Answer (score 0):

Поиск по Гуглу дал: http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/127446 , ссылка на словарь Ожегова.